# Is it possible to open a ios app from web link

Tags: ios, ipad

I have a PWA and want to open a photo app (maßband) with a link.
Example:
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id

Is it possible and how can I get the ID from the app maßband. This app is build by apple.
Is it possible to get the ID with Apple Store connect?

thanks in advance